# How to convert Unstructured Text data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data-set in which one column looks like this:

```
Log_column

A: 1 B:2 Action Type: This data is not relevant
A: 1 B:4 
Action Type: Hello World D:90
Null
E:500-----K:"Hello"
```

Every entry in a column is kind of long key:value pair without separated by comma. How can I get a dataframe like this:

```
  A   B   Action Type   D      E    K
  1    2   some_text    Null Null  Null
  1    4     Null       Null Null  Null
```

---

How can I solve this using Pandas and Numpy? The column name can have spaces and makes it more difficult to parse.

However if we know column names then does it solve the problem?

Comment: Where is column `D` coming from?

Comment: I think your expected output needs a bit more focus. Are you saying only the values for keys `['A', 'B'` are relevant? Everything else is to be `nan`? Otherwise, what is `some_text` in row 1 column `Action Type`. Do you know the expected keys in advance or are they dynamic? If not known in advance, keys with spaces ("Action Type") are almost impossible to parse properly